# How can I get a value returned from a then clause when select data using mysql

Tags: node.js, express, promise

I am trying to finish a login functionality with mysql and express. I got a work_id and a user_password, and I want to use the work_id to find whether the user exists in my database. I use promise to do this, I can log the selected user information in the console, but the promise is always pending, and the web storm console didn't terminate.
What I want is a boolean value from the promise, whether the user exists or not.
Here is my code:
query.js.

```js
const pool = require('./connect');
module.exports = {
    query: function (sqlString, params) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            pool.getConnection(function (err, connection) {
                if (err) {
                    reject(err)
                } else {
                    connection.query(sqlString, params, (err, rows) => {
                        if (err) {
                            reject(err)
                        } else {
                            resolve(rows)
                        }
                        connection.release()
                    })
                }
            })
        })
    }
}
```

sqlCRUD.js, about the sql statement

```js
const user = {
    queryByWorkId: 'select * from user_info where work_id=?',
    queryAll: 'select * from user_info',
    resetPassword: 'update user_info set user_password = ? where work_id = ?',
};
```

user.js, I execute the test here.

```js
const Model = require('./main')
const crypto = require('crypto')
const _ = require('./query')
const $sqlQuery = require('./sqlCRUD').user

class User{
  // others
  static findOne(form={}) {
  const { work_id, user_password } = form
  return _.query($sqlQuery.queryByWorkId, work_id)
            .then(res => {
                console.log(res)
                if (res.length > 0) {
                    const u = res[0]
                    return u
                }
                return false
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('User.findOne error', err)
                return {
                    errmsg: JSON.stringify(err)
                }
            })
    }
```

Here is my test, in user.js

```js
const test = () => {
    const form = {
        work_id: '007',
        user_password: 'root',
    }
    const r = User.findOne(form)
    console.log('r', r)
}
```

And this is the output:
[I am not allowed to embed a picture here, so SO generates a link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TG1o5.png)

I got confused about this: in my query.js file, I return a promise, in my User.findOne(form={}) method, I call it with a then and catch,
return _.query($sqlQuery.queryByWorkId, work_id).then(res => console.log(res)).catch(err => console.log(err)), but the console did't terminate, and I just got a Promise {  }.

What's wrong with my code? How can I get a value returned from a then clause in promise when select data using mysql? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I return the response from an asynchronous call?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: @uncleliu, your `test` function runs without anything that makes it await a promise resolve.

Comment: @HeyJude  , I don't understand it. Add a then clause after findOne, like this? const r = User.findOne(form).then(res => console.log(res))

Comment: @uncleliu, right. Did that solve it? If not, what happens?

Comment: @HeyJude  , no. It didn't help. The web storm console printed the res out, but after that, the console is still running, I had to close it manully, which wasn't what I want.

Comment: @Roamer-1888 , hi, I don't that post helps. I read several times, but  still I can not figure it out. Can you tell me where was wrong?

Comment: @uncleliu, if promises weren't involved, what would cause the web storm console to terminate?

Comment: @Roamer-1888   just press the stop button, or ctrl-c